# How do you escape curly braces ({ }) in emmet in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Specifically, I'd like to escape two curly braces, in VSCode.

Often time I find myself writing templates like this:

```html
<div class="something">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

While `<p>text</p>` can be easily achieved with `p{text}`, I am stumped on how would one be able to achieve `<p>{{ value }}</p>` using an emmet shorthand.

It would be great if anyone can point out how to achieve this via emmet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no resolution: Problem is a bug and has been filed under vscode issue tracker

Comment: I would add a link to the issue you filed and leave the question open at least until that issue is resolved.  Other people are more likely to find it here than on github.

Comment: I left out the issue that I've created https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127919

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work by escaping the `}` characters. Here's an example:

```
a[href="{{ site:url }}"]{{{ site:name \}\}}
```

Renders:

```html
<a href="{{ site:url }}">{{ site:name }}</a>
```